# facebook and social preview of a website aren't working (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

i'm working on my website but i can't find a way to make facebook and social og: tag work.
The preview is not working on any social or chat.

I've added all the field through Yoast, added main image in the wordpress page, and so on.

It works on any tester that i've tried, but it doesn't work in the fact.
Facebook debugger says that the code misses the og: tags.

Any help? thanks!

This is the website: [www.studioimmobiliaremoreno.it](http://www.studioimmobiliaremoreno.it)

This is the og: code:

```
<meta name="description" content="Lo Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado con servizi innovativi per chi cerca, vende o affittare casa ad Avellino e provincia o in Campania." />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="it_IT" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Home - Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado - Avellino" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lo Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado con servizi innovativi per chi cerca, vende o affittare casa ad Avellino e provincia o in Campania." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2021-08-24T08:40:54+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/moreno-corrado-studio-immobiliare-incarichi-open-servizi.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1152" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="768" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:label1" content="Tempo di lettura stimato" />
<meta name="twitter:data1" content="31 minuti" />
<script type="application/ld+json" class="yoast-schema-graph">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@graph":[{"@type":"Organization","@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#organization","name":"Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado","url":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/","sameAs":[],"logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#logo","inLanguage":"it-IT","url":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/logo-short.jpg","contentUrl":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/logo-short.jpg","width":2001,"height":2218,"caption":"Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado"},"image":{"@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#logo"}},{"@type":"WebSite","@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#website","url":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/","name":"Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado","description":"","publisher":{"@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#organization"},"potentialAction":[{"@type":"SearchAction","target":{"@type":"EntryPoint","urlTemplate":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/?s={search_term_string}"},"query-input":"required name=search_term_string"}],"inLanguage":"it-IT"},{"@type":"ImageObject","@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#primaryimage","inLanguage":"it-IT","url":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/moreno-corrado-studio-immobiliare-incarichi-open-servizi.jpg","contentUrl":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/moreno-corrado-studio-immobiliare-incarichi-open-servizi.jpg","width":1152,"height":768,"caption":"studio immobiliare moreno corrado avellino per vendere casa"},{"@type":"WebPage","@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#webpage","url":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/","name":"Home - Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado - Avellino","isPartOf":{"@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#website"},"about":{"@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#organization"},"primaryImageOfPage":{"@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#primaryimage"},"datePublished":"2020-06-26T11:34:06+00:00","dateModified":"2021-08-24T08:40:54+00:00","description":"Lo Studio Immobiliare Moreno Corrado con servizi innovativi per chi cerca, vende o affittare casa ad Avellino e provincia o in Campania.","breadcrumb":{"@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#breadcrumb"},"inLanguage":"it-IT","potentialAction":[{"@type":"ReadAction","target":["https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/"]}]},{"@type":"BreadcrumbList","@id":"https://studioimmobiliaremoreno.it/#breadcrumb","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"name":"Home"}]}]}</script>
<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->
```